# How can I group by distinct value into a (value,count) array in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

for example, I have a table A

```sql
create table A (
    id Int64,
    discrete1 String
    discrete2 String
) engine=Log;
```

and some data

```sql
insert into A values
(1,'A','a')
(1,'B','b')
(1,'A','c')
(2,'C','a')
(1,'A','a');
```

How can I select this result,the tuple is (value,count)

```sql
1,[(A,3),(B,1)],[(a,2),(b,1),(c,1)]
2,[(C,1)],[(a,1)]
```

My table may have many discrete value columns, is there any way to do that in one select without group by discrete value columns one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id,
    arrayMap((x, y) -> (x, y),
      (arrayReduce('sumMap', [(groupArrayArray([discrete1]) as arrdiscrete1)], 
              [arrayResize(CAST([], 'Array(UInt64)'), length(arrdiscrete1), toUInt64(1))]) as sdiscrete1).1,
      sdiscrete1.2) rdiscrete1,
    arrayMap((x, y) -> (x, y),
      (arrayReduce('sumMap', [(groupArrayArray([discrete2]) as arrdiscrete2)], 
              [arrayResize(CAST([], 'Array(UInt64)'), length(arrdiscrete2), toUInt64(1))]) as sdiscrete2).1,
      sdiscrete2.2) rdiscrete2
FROM A
GROUP BY id

┌─id─┬─rdiscrete1────────┬─rdiscrete2────────────────┐
│  2 │ [('C',1)]         │ [('a',1)]                 │
│  1 │ [('A',3),('B',1)] │ [('a',2),('b',1),('c',1)] │
└────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I got error when run your query： 
Received exception from server (version 19.17.2):
Code: 43. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse-server:9000. DB::Exception: Illegal type of argument for aggregate function sumMap.

Comment: because of strings , v20.3.2.1, 2020-03-12 Add support of String and FixedString keys for sumMap

Answer (score 1):

Try this query (you need just define the required 'discrete'-columns and their count):

```sql
SELECT id, groupArray(result_per_id_column) result_per_id
FROM (
    SELECT id, groupArray(count_result) result_per_id_column
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, index_discrete.1 as index, (index_discrete.2,  count()) AS count_result
        FROM 
        (   
            SELECT id, arrayJoin(arrayMap((x, index) -> (index, x),
                            [discrete1, discrete2, discrete3 /* so on for other 'discrete'-columns */],
                            range(3 /* count of 'discrete'-columns */))) index_discrete
            FROM (
                /* test data */
                SELECT 
                    data.1 AS id, 
                    data.2 AS discrete1,
                    data.3 AS discrete2,
                    data.4 AS discrete3
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT arrayJoin([(1, 'A', 'a', 'aa'), (1, 'B', 'b', 'aa'), (1, 'A', 'c', 'bb'), (2, 'C', 'a', 'bb'), (1, 'A', 'a', 'cc')]) AS data
                )))
        GROUP BY id, index_discrete.1, index_discrete.2
    )
    GROUP BY id, index
    ORDER BY id, index)
GROUP BY id
/* result
┌─id─┬─result_per_id──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  1 │ [[('A',3),('B',1)],[('a',2),('b',1),('c',1)],[('cc',1),('bb',1),('aa',2)]] │
│  2 │ [[('C',1)],[('a',1)],[('bb',1)]]                                           │
└────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question.

Comment: I fixed the answer, take into account that returns just one column with Array-type for the set of 'discrete'-columns instead of many columns.

Comment: Thanks. It seems there is no more 'direct' support for this requirement. Maybe clickhouse can have some aggregate function like groupCountArray etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id,
    sumMap(arr, arrayResize(CAST([], 'Array(UInt64)'), length(arr), toUInt64(1))) AS s
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        groupArrayArray([discrete1, discrete2]) AS arr
    FROM A
    GROUP BY id
)
GROUP BY id

┌─id─┬─s───────────────────────────────────┐
│  2 │ (['C','a'],[1,1])                   │
│  1 │ (['A','B','a','b','c'],[3,1,2,1,1]) │
└────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘


SELECT
    id,
    arrayMap((x, y) -> (x, y), (sumMap(arr, arrayResize(CAST([], 'Array(UInt64)'), length(arr), toUInt64(1))) AS s).1, s.2) AS r
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        groupArrayArray([discrete1, discrete2]) AS arr
    FROM A
    GROUP BY id
)
GROUP BY id

┌─id─┬─r─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  2 │ [('C',1),('a',1)]                         │
│  1 │ [('A',3),('B',1),('a',2),('b',1),('c',1)] │
└────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘


SELECT
    id,
    arrayMap((x, y) -> (x, y),
      (arrayReduce('sumMap', [(groupArrayArray([discrete1, discrete2]) as arr)], 
              [arrayResize(CAST([], 'Array(UInt64)'), length(arr), toUInt64(1))]) as s).1,
      s.2) r
FROM A
GROUP BY id
┌─id─┬─r─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  2 │ [('C',1),('a',1)]                         │
│  1 │ [('A',3),('B',1),('a',2),('b',1),('c',1)] │
└────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I don't want to combine all discrete column together，I want  to compute their percentage separately

Comment: @xiemeilong I've added one more answer